# How to make buttons act as radiobuttons with jquery?

Tags: jquery, button

I have two groups of buttons and i like to have the buttons act like radio buttons so just one can be selected.

For example:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="span2">                         
    <input type=button  value="10" id="top_A" name="top_A" onclick="yourPick(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
    <input type=button  value="20" id="top_B" name="top_B" onclick="yourPick(this)"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div  id="bottom">
    <div class="span2">                         
    <input type=button value="30" id="top_C" name="top_C" onclick="yourPick(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
    <input type=button  value="40" id="top_D" name="top_D" onclick="yourPick(this)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can select just button 10 or 20 in top vs 30 or 40 in div bottom.

Any suggestions?

ps:

```
function yourpick(pick){
    var pValue= pick.value;
    alert(pValue);
    $('#topPick').val(pValue); 
    $('#bottomPick').val(pValue); 
}
```

Comment: How about http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio from jquery ui?

Comment: Whats wrong with radio buttons?

Comment: @csharpsi , interface is based on buttons at the moment. So for the user i like to use buttons all the way. matt looks promising i am going to check it

Comment: @matt i am right to assume your link uses radiobutton which look like buttons by adding a label between the begin - end tag??

Comment: @alex, yes they act just like radio buttons, but they are styled as buttons. You can just the jquery theme roller to style it as you please. Then use you add a label and what's in between will be the text shown. So this is valid HTML plus compatible if someone doesn't have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i would agree with user832715 on the usage of disabled attribute of the buttons.

$("#selectButton1DivA").attr("disabled", false/true");

Answer (score 4):

I removed onclick attributes from your examble, but you can use attribute disabled to selected button in the group and enable all others. Thats how they behave like radiobuttons.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    handleGroup('#top .span2 input');
    handleGroup('#bottom .span2 input');

});


function handleGroup(selector) {
    var inputs = $(selector);

    inputs.live('click', function () {

        //this returns id if needed
        //alert($(this).attr('id'));

        inputs.attr('disabled','');

        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

    });
}
```

Comment: i am also trying your suggestion but the buttons don't seem to switch. I mean when i select one of the #top buttons i can't select the other one.